# Obtain error: cannot find -lopencv_dep_cudart while building project on Ubuntu 16

Tags: opencv, ubuntu-16.04

While building project on Ubuntu 16 which uses OpenCV I'm obtaining linker error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_dep_cudart
```

Comment: The project is described using cmake lists. So, while preparing makefiles I'm using cmake

Answer (score 0):

Solution: set `-D CUDA_USE_STATIC_CUDA_RUNTIME=OFF` while running cmake.
I've also tried to add that parameter to CMakeLists.txt but this doesn't always help.